# Is it Possible to use windsor Castle with WCF services

Tags: .net, wcf, castle-windsor

is it possible to use Castle Windsor with WCF services ?

I tried to use it and instead going to the contractor with parameters I see that it goes to the default contractor and I am curious why it is doing so ?

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dm = new DependencyManager(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "API");
            dm.Container.Install(new Installer());

        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can but your question is a little vague. Are you trying to start a service or are you trying to inject a client proxy? Can you show an example of what you have done?

EDIT

To start a new wcf service you will need to use the `WcfFacility`. You are using an installer which you don't show so you may already be wiiring up the facility in there.

```cs
container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
```

Once you have registered all your components you can start the service with the `DefaultServiceHostFactory` which is included in the WCF facility.

```cs
var host = (ServiceHost)new DefaultServiceHostFactory().CreateServiceHost(typeof(YourService).AssemblyQualifiedName, new Uri[] { });
host.Open();
```

Comment: I am trying to start a service.

Comment: seems that I am not using not the latest (2.5.3) version , I need to upgrade to v3